# need to know how to re-write it to Volley

Tags: android

I tried to re-write the code to volley code but the issue still not working. Kindly i need your support to help me in this issue

This code is working well

```js
@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")){

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

I need to convert it to this but there is error

```js
public void UserLoginFunction(final String email, final String password){

        CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();
        //getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(LoginActivity.UserEmail) is to get the username and display all value that belong to it
        String url = PhpLink.Login+"?email="+email+"&"+"password="+password ;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response){
                try{
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched"));

                    //    data_list.clear(); it used for refreash the page and clean page before refreash
                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        // get userid and all data to use again in the activity
                        String getShared_ID= jsonObject.getString("users_id");
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("id", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                        editor.putString("users_id", jsonObject.getString("users_id"));
```

[image]

Comment: what did you want here? `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched"));
`. The `response.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")` return with true or false and `JSONArray` doesn't have constructor with boolean parameter.

Comment: I want to try to match the "data matched " in PHP file.

Comment: At first check the response and after that try to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a `try` block, but can't see the rest of the code. Make sure you catch `JSONException` in the `catch` block.